# Sort alphabetically elements in array of object (error)

Tags: javascript, sorting

Well, when i'm trying to use the array like this `let titles = ["Julian","August"]` the `.sort()` works, but when i try to use like that

```
function showTitles(jsonObj) {
    let filmes = jsonObj.filmes;
    for (let i = 0; i < filmes.length; i++) {
        let titles = [];
        titles.push(filmes[i].title);
        console.log(titles.sort());
    }
}
```

doesn't work. I have a json of objects with titles and I want to sort this alphabetically.

the json:

```
{
  "filmes": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "title": "Os Simpsons O Filme",
      "url": "https://youtu.be/KCpcGsFl90c",
      "image": "sMcsZ7BlOf2LDhTlfPlWb3w6lJM.jpg",
      "sinopse": "Homer Simpson.",
      "time": "1h:26m",
      "quality": "720p",
      "latestAdded": false,
      "problem": false,
      "release": "27/07/2007",
      "version": "Dublado",
      "gender": [
        "Animação",
        "Comédia"
      ]
    }
}
```

Please if someone knows how to do this works, help me :/

Comment: Is "filmes" an array inside of the jsonObj?

Comment: i have edited the ask for see the complete json

Comment: do you want to sort the object by its keys, so do you want to get output like this:
  "filmes": [
    {
      "a":"01",
      "b": "lorem",
      "z": "dummy",
    }

Answer (score 2):

`let` is block scoped. This means it only exists inside the `{ }` it was created in. Each iteration of your for loop is creating a branch new `titles` variable that is empty. You then sort it with only one value in it.

Here's another way to write it so that you aren't losing the variable each iteration:

```
function showTitles(jsonObj) {
    let filmes = jsonObj.filmes;
    let titles = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < filmes.length; i++) {
        titles.push(filmes[i].title);
    }

    console.log(titles.sort());
}
```

There's also a great built in map function that can reduce the amount of code for this. It uses a lot of ES6 syntax, so if you are new to JS I don't recommend using it until you have a good grasp of the fundamentals.

```
let titles = jsonObj.filmes.map(({ title }) => title);
console.log(titles.sort());
```

Comment: i'm js begginer, but thansk for tip, and the answer

Comment: thank you, but, when i do that, and trying to have just 1 value, i cant, because print all in one

Comment: If you only want one, then just `console.log(titles[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize the array inside of for loop because it Will reset in every new loop

```
    function showTitles(jsonObj) {
        let filmes = jsonObj.filmes;
        let titles = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < filmes.length; i++) {
  
         titles.push(filmes[i].title);
        }
     console.log(titles.sort());
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but, when i do that, and trying to have just 1 value, i cant, because print all in one

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you posted JSON or a JavaScript object literal; it is neither valid JS nor valid JSON because you can't have an empty value like `"id": ,`. Did you mean:

```
{
      "id": '',
      "title": "Ratatouille",
      "url": '',
      "image": '',
      "sinopse": '',
      "time": '',
      "quality": '',
      "latestAdded": '',
      "problem": '',
      "release": '',
      "version": '',
      "gender": [

      ]
}
```

In that case, your method won't work because there is no property `filmes` on the object.

Also, your naming of the parameter as `jsonObj` doesn't make sense -- JSON is parsed into a regular JavaScript object, so did you mean to call it something like `filmesObj`?

Comment: I have, look i will edit the code for you see, wait please